# LayoutInflater: Getting Data with baseAdapter and the layouts aren't inserted

Tags: android, database, adapter

Hy guys!

I've a big problem. I am triing to display data from a sqlite database in a listview using a baseadapter. for this i created a class for my baseadapter where i define it. Everthing works fine i am getting 10 rows from the cursor but nothing is displayed. Maybe i should replace the Layoutinflater to a different place. Please help me!

My error is something with an id.

**Here is my adapterclass:**

```
public class RouteAdapterActivity extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> arraylist;

    public RouteAdapterActivity(Context context, ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> list) {
        this.context = context;
        arraylist = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        DefineRouteActivity routeItems = arraylist.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.outputlayout,null);

        TextView tvDeparture = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputDeparture);
        tvDeparture.setText(routeItems.getAbfahrtszeit());
        TextView tvDuration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputDuration);
        tvDuration.setText(routeItems.getDauer());
        TextView tvTransition = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputTransition);
        tvTransition.setText(routeItems.getUmstieg());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**here is my cursor adapter:**

```
public void getRoute() {
    lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvView);
    mdbH = new DatabaseHelperActivity(this);
    cursor = mdbH.fetchallRoutes(mdbH);
    ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> route = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();
    RouteAdapterActivity adapter = new RouteAdapterActivity(PlanOutputActivity.this, route);

    lvList.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

**and finally here is my layout which should be inserted into the listview:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/outputlayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/ligthgrey"
    android:onClick="layoutOutput">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputDeparture"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Abfahrt "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxLength="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputDuration"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDeparture"
        android:text="Dauer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputTransition"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDuration"
        android:text="Umstieg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my cursor Statement:**

```
SELECT f.id, strftime('%H:%M', f.abfahrt) AS Abfahrt," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', f.ankunft) AS Ankunft," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', strftime('%s',f.ankunft)- strftime('%s',f.abfahrt), 'unixepoch') AS Dauer," +
                "r.name AS Route," +
                "count(u.fahrt_id) AS Umstiege " +
                "FROM scotty_fahrt f " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle start ON f.start_id = start.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle ziel ON f.ziel_id = ziel.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_route r ON f.route_id = r.id " +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN scotty_umstiegsstelle u ON f.id = u.fahrt_id " +
                "WHERE start.name = 'Haibach ob der Donau Ortsmitte' " +
                "AND ziel.name = 'Neufelden Busterminal (Schulzentrum)' " +
                "GROUP BY u.fahrt_id
```

Here is my DefineRouteActivity:

```
public class DefineRouteActivity {
    private String abfahrtszeit;
    private String dauer;
    private String umstieg;

    public DefineRouteActivity(String abfahrtszeit, String dauer, String umstieg)
    {
        this.abfahrtszeit = abfahrtszeit;
        this.dauer = dauer;
        this.umstieg = umstieg;
    }

    public String getAbfahrtszeit() {
        return abfahrtszeit;
    }


    public String getDauer() {
        return dauer;
    }

    public String getUmstieg() {
        return umstieg;
    }
}
```

Please help me!!

Comment: I didn't understand your error, can you put a logcat?

Comment: oh sorry wrong question i am editing it rigth now

Answer (score 0):

when you do this lines:

```
cursor = mdbH.fetchallRoutes(mdbH);
ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> route = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();
```

And you pass the route to the adapter the route is empty. You have to transform your cursor in an Arraylist.

Do you know how to pass from a cursor to an array of objects? 
If you create a method you can do this:

```
route= getRouteFromCursor(cursor);
```

and then create the adapter like you are doing now.

EDIT: Because I don't understand the language in your code I am going to give you an example.
Insert the following method (change the `ColumnIndex` to the name that you have in your database):

```
ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> getRouteFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> routes = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

        try {
            String abfahrtszeit = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("abfahrtszeit")); // here you put the column name of the value you want to retrieve

            String dauer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dauer"));

            String umstieg = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("umstieg"));

            routes.add(new DefineRouteActivity(abfahrtszeit, dauer, umstieg));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return routes;
}
```

Now, before you create your adapter change your code to this:

```
cursor = mdbH.fetchallRoutes(mdbH);
ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> route = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();
route= getRouteFromCursor(cursor);
RouteAdapterActivity adapter = new RouteAdapterActivity(PlanOutputActivity.this, route);
```

All set.

Comment: i am not able to do this... please help me i added the DefineRouteActivity